# Plotting different Regions in RevolutionPlot3D

Tags: plotting

sorry this might be a trivial question, but I can't find a neat way to express this plot in simple terms. I am sure there is a better way than to 'boole everything else out', because I have to adjust the plot range manually every time and it is just not the nice way to code.

RegionFunction does not seem to work properly with RevolutionPlot3D (it seems to act on the 'plotted-y-axis' rather than on the circumferential coordinate (theta).

.[image]

```
I1 = Pi/2;  
f1 = Cos[Pi*r];
f2 = Sin[Pi*r];
f3 = Sin[2*Pi*r];
f4 = 1 - Cos[2*Pi*r];
I1 =  Pi/2;
l1 = \[Theta] >= I1;
l2 = 1*I1 >=   \[Theta] ||  \[Theta] >= 2*I1;
l3 = 2*I1 >=  \[Theta] || \[Theta] >= 3*I1;
l4 = 3*I1 >=  \[Theta];
RevolutionPlot3D[{{f1 - Boole[l1]*100}, {f2 - 100*Boole[l2]}, {f3 - 
100*Boole[l3]}, {f4 - 100*Boole[l4]}}, {r, 0, 1}, {\[Theta], 0, 
  2*Pi}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-2, 2}}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"f1", "f2", "f3", "f4"}]
```

Thank you very much in advance for every possible idea / solution.

Best
P

Comment: Maybe `Show`? https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html

Comment: I don't see a `RegionFunction` in your code....  Here's an example of it working:  `RevolutionPlot3D[t^4 - t^2, {t, 0, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, -.2 < z < -.1]]`

Comment: @JasonB:  The OP notes that region function works for $x$, $y$, and $z$, but he would prefer a simple and natural reliance on $\theta$ and $r$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork -  I still think it could be clearer what is meant, but that's simple to fix `RevolutionPlot3D[{Sin[t], t}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z, t, \[Theta]}, \[Pi]/2 < \[Theta] < 3 \[Pi]/2]]`

Comment: Thanks for the working example of 
RegionFunction, because I was using the same variable twice, which caused an error.
Question solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RegionFunction` takes 6 arguments, `x,y,z,t,theta,r` , so a function of angle is like this:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{f1}, {r, 0, 1}, {\[Theta], 0, 2*Pi}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-2, 2}}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"f1", "f2", "f3", "f4"}, 
 RegionFunction :> (0 < #5 < Pi/2 &)]
```

[image]

this is in the docs for `RevolutionPlot3D`, under `Options` `RegionFunction`

I don't see how to specify different `RegionFunction`'s for different functions so to make your original its like this:

```
Show[MapThread[
  RevolutionPlot3D[#1, {r, 0, 1}, {\[Theta], 0, 2*Pi}, 
    RegionFunction -> #2, PlotStyle -> #3] &,
  Transpose[{
    {f1, 0 < #5 < Pi/2 &, Red},
    {f2, Pi/2 < #5 < Pi &, Green},
    {f2, Pi < #5 < 3 Pi/2 &, Blue},
    {f2, 3 Pi/2 < #5 < 2 Pi &, Black}
    }]], PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image]

(and really i don't think the `Boole` approach is so bad..)